# Flutter app crashes just after wallpaper is set

Tags: android, flutter, crash, wallpaper, miui

flutter android application goes to hang state and immediately crashes just after wallpaper is set from the app.The wallpaper changes automatically every minute.
This crash issue was not found on my nokia device this error was found on a redmi device
This is my code below....

also this code is called in a periodic function using

await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
const Duration(minutes: 1), 1, myfunction);

```
``
  static Future<void> myfunction()async{
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            "my url here"));
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        results = jsonData;
        var url = results["urls"]["full"];
        String result;
        var progressString = Wallpaper.imageDownloadProgress(url);

        progressString.listen((data) {
          print("DataReceived: " + data);
        }, onDone: () async {
          if (Globals.selectedScreen.toString() == 'home') {
            try {
              await Wallpaper.homeScreen();
            } catch (e) {
              debugPrint(e);
            }
          } else if (Globals.selectedScreen.toString() == 'lock') {
            try {
              await Wallpaper.lockScreen();
            } catch (e) {
              debugPrint(e);
            }
          } else {
            try {
              await Wallpaper.bothScreen();
            } catch (e) {
              debugPrint(e);
            }
          }
        }}`
`
```

`this is my terminal output when app got crashed

`
DataReceived: 100%

> W/MIUIScout App(13194): Enter APP_SCOUT_WARNING State W/MIUIScout
> App(13194): Event:APP_SCOUT_WARNING Thread:main backtrace: W/MIUIScout
> App(13194):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native
> Method) W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1445) W/MIUIScout
> App(13194):     at
> android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:1535)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:1506)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> com.prateektimer.wallpaper.WallpaperPlugin.setHomeLockScreen(WallpaperPlugin.java:182)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> com.prateektimer.wallpaper.WallpaperPlugin.onMethodCall(WallpaperPlugin.java:91)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown
> Source:12) W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) W/MIUIScout
> App(13194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) W/MIUIScout App(13194):
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) W/MIUIScout App(13194):
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
> W/MIUIScout App(13194):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037) I/libc
> (13194): Requested dump for tid 13194 (ample.app)`